# Is there a shortcut to fuse individual elements of two same sized Array of an Array of Strings?

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two array of array of string

```
[["1,'TambaÃº','PraÃ§a Santo AntÃ³nio','TambaÃº','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,6,5934,50"], 
 ["2,'Beira Rio','Av. Bei ra Rio, Prox. Av Odilon Coutinho','Beira Rio','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,0,7249,0"], 
 ["3,'Cabo Branco','Cabo Bra nco, Prox. Rua Alice de Almeida','Cabo Branco','12x0',2,'I','EO',12,0,4751,0"], 
 ["901,'teste','teste','test e','Mini-estaÃ§Ã£o de demonstraÃ§Ã£o',1,'I','EO',2,1,97,50"]
]

[["-7.1105596,-34.824085"],
 ["-7.1243144,-34.823312"],
 ["-7.1395805,-34.816446"],
 ["-7.1008926,-35.068359"]]
```

I can do it the manual way with looping and adding elements, but I was wondering if anyone knew if a smarter way exists.

EDIT: Here's the result I want to solve any confusion

```
[
 "1,'TambaÃº','PraÃ§a Santo AntÃ³nio','TambaÃº','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,6,5934,50,-7.1105596,-34.824085",
 "2,' Beira Rio','Av. Beira Rio, Prox. Av Odilon Coutinho','Beira Rio','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,0,7249,0,-7.1243144, -34.823312",
 "3,'Cabo Branco','Cabo Branco, Prox. Rua Alice de Almeida','Cabo Branco','12x0',2,'I','EO',12, 0,4751,0,-7.1395805,-34.816446", 
 "901,'teste','teste','teste','Mini-estaÃ§Ã£o de demonstraÃ§Ã£o',1,'I','EO' ,2,1,97,50,-7.1008926,-35.068359"
]
```

Here's what I'm doing right now

```
for i in 0...arr1.size
  newArr[i] = (arr1[i][0] + "," + arr2[i][0])
end
```

Comment: What do you mean "fuse"? What is your expected output?

Comment: Why do you need the array in array? To represent the data you show in your example an array of strings would be enough. With `Array#flatten` you may create such an array of string. When you write _fuse_ - what should be the result? concatenate the String of array 1 with the string of array 2? Or do you want an array of array of two strings?

Comment: In any case `Array#flatten` and `Array#zip` probably are your friends.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - I meant concatenate. This is the expected result `["1,'TambaÃº','PraÃ§a Santo AntÃ³nio','TambaÃº','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,6,5934,50,-7.1105596,-34.824085", "2,'
Beira Rio','Av. Beira Rio,  Prox. Av Odilon Coutinho','Beira Rio','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,0,7249,0,-7.1243144,
-34.823312", "3,'Cabo Branco','Cabo Branco, Prox. Rua Alice de Almeida','Cabo Branco','12x0',2,'I','EO',12,
0,4751,0,-7.1395805,-34.816446", "901,'teste','teste','teste','Mini-estaÃ§Ã£o de demonstraÃ§Ã£o',1,'I','EO'
,2,1,97,50,-7.1008926,-35.068359"]`

Comment: @NiklasB. and knut - I didn't know about flatten and zip. Thanks, I'll take a look at those.

Comment: I highly recommend familiarizing yourself with all the methods available on Array and Enumerable (as well as other primitive types). Therein lies the power and conciseness of Ruby.

Comment: @JohnSmith Please edit your question with the new information, it's very difficult to parse that in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flatten` and `zip`, then `map` a `join`:

```
arr1 = [
  ["1,'TambaÃº','PraÃ§a Santo AntÃ³nio','TambaÃº','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,6,5934,50"], 
  ["2,'Beira Rio','Av. Bei ra Rio, Prox. Av Odilon Coutinho','Beira Rio','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,0,7249,0"], 
  ["3,'Cabo Branco','Cabo Bra nco, Prox. Rua Alice de Almeida','Cabo Branco','12x0',2,'I','EO',12,0,4751,0"], 
  ["901,'teste','teste','test e','Mini-estaÃ§Ã£o de demonstraÃ§Ã£o',1,'I','EO',2,1,97,50"]
]

arr2 = [
  ["-7.1105596,-34.824085"],
  ["-7.1243144,-34.823312"],
  ["-7.1395805,-34.816446"],
  ["-7.1008926,-35.068359"]
]

arr1.flatten.zip(arr2.flatten).map { |pair| pair.join(',') }
#=> ["1,'Tamba','Praa Santo Antnio','Tamba','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,6,5934,50,-7.1105596,-34.824085"],
#    "2,'Beira Rio','Av. Bei ra Rio, Prox. Av Odilon Coutinho','Beira Rio','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,0,7249,0,-7.1243144,-34.823312",
#    "3,'Cabo Branco','Cabo Bra nco, Prox. Rua Alice de Almeida','Cabo Branco','12x0',2,'I','EO',12,0,4751,0,-7.1395805,-34.816446",
#    "901,'teste','teste','test e','Mini-estao de demonstrao',1,'I','EO',2,1,97,50,-7.1008926,-35.068359"]
```

Comment: Thank You! That map function is new to me.

Answer (score 1):

This solution keeps the array in array (Arr1 will be modified!)

```
arr1 = [
  ["1,'TambaÃº','PraÃ§a Santo AntÃ³nio','TambaÃº','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,6,5934,50"], 
  ["2,'Beira Rio','Av. Bei ra Rio, Prox. Av Odilon Coutinho','Beira Rio','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,0,7249,0"], 
  ["3,'Cabo Branco','Cabo Bra nco, Prox. Rua Alice de Almeida','Cabo Branco','12x0',2,'I','EO',12,0,4751,0"], 
  ["901,'teste','teste','test e','Mini-estaÃ§Ã£o de demonstraÃ§Ã£o',1,'I','EO',2,1,97,50"]
]

arr2 = [["-7.1105596,-34.824085"], ["-7.1243144,-34.823312"], ["-7.1395805,-34.816446"], ["-7.1008926,-35.068359"]]


arr1.each_with_index{|el,i|
  el.first << ',' 
  el.first << arr2[i].first
}
```

With `arr1.flatten!` you may make a 'normal' array out of your array of array.

You may also do the `flatten` before you 'fuse':

```
arr1 = [
  ["1,'TambaÃº','PraÃ§a Santo AntÃ³nio','TambaÃº','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,6,5934,50"], 
  ["2,'Beira Rio','Av. Bei ra Rio, Prox. Av Odilon Coutinho','Beira Rio','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,0,7249,0"], 
  ["3,'Cabo Branco','Cabo Bra nco, Prox. Rua Alice de Almeida','Cabo Branco','12x0',2,'I','EO',12,0,4751,0"], 
  ["901,'teste','teste','test e','Mini-estaÃ§Ã£o de demonstraÃ§Ã£o',1,'I','EO',2,1,97,50"]
]
arr1.flatten!

arr2 = [["-7.1105596,-34.824085"], ["-7.1243144,-34.823312"], ["-7.1395805,-34.816446"], ["-7.1008926,-35.068359"]]
arr2.flatten!

arr1.each_with_index{|el,i|
  el << ','
  el << arr2[i]
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh capitalized variable names and multiline `{}`! Whyyyyyy?

Comment: Capitalized variable names make it a constant.

Comment: Sorry, I copied from an existing solution and didn't look at the names - it's late in the night for me ;) I modified the example.

Comment: This works but I'm confused about that each_with_index function you used. It's not listed in the ruby docs, however there is a close method each_index, is this the same ? [http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-each_index](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-each_index)

Comment: @devcoder [`each_with_index` comes from Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index). Array includes Enumerable so it gets it too.